# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of while creating a JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json

I'm simply trying to create JSON object like that:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JsonUtility().execute(UrlUtility.url + "/" + lessonUrl).get());
```

Error occurs here ^ with message received in `catch` block:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

`JsonUtility` class as follows (I belive problem lies not there but still):

```
    private class JsonUtility extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new URL(params[0]).openStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Reading Json into StringBuilder
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            // Converting Json from StringBuilder to String
            result = sBuilder.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You see that response is concatenated from strings (due to application logic). The final string is: `http://itvdn-api.azurewebsites.net/api/courses/test-driven-development/tdd-introduction`. As you see when I redirect to that link it gives JSON response.

I have tried to evaluate this `UrlUtility.url` and received that: 
[image]

That weird ending of char array confuses me. Perhabs its the problem. Tried to replace those characters using `String.replaceAll("'\u0000'0", "" )`. Didnt work.

Please help. Will appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**

Also, when I hardcode link as:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JsonUtility().execute("http://itvdn-api.azurewebsites.net/api/courses/test-driven-development/tdd-introduction").get());
```

It works!

---

**EDIT #2 @ ρяσѕρєя K**

`result = sBuilder.toString();` is empty - `""` since it can't parse that concatenated string.

*Note: I've been using the same parser with different links in this application e.g. http://itvdn-api.azurewebsites.net/api/courses and that was working fine (but there was no concatenation with link)*

Comment: what you are getting as final response `result = sBuilder.toString();` ? and also no need to add "\n" for json string with line

Comment: Use `byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
   StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
   int numRead = 0;
   while ((numRead = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) 
    x.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));`

Comment: @jitainsharma What should I write in Overriden method `read()` from InputStream? It returns 0 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
     * Convert InputStream into String
     * @param is
     * @return
     * @throws IOException Throws an IO Exception if input stream cannot be read
     */
    public static String stringFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        if (is != null) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
            int numRead = 0;
            while ((numRead = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) 
                x.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));
            return x.toString();
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Use this method for reading the inputstream and get the string.

Comment: I don't really understand how to use it. I belive I should use this method in `doInBackground` method but then all those `BufferedReaders` are not working. If you could show practical example of usage that would've been awesome

Comment: I have post this method just to get the inputstream and read the bytes, appends in to the stringBuilder, here we read 1024 bytes at a time. Also your using  + "\n", remove this as well and check.